# Conditional mapped typed with unions make functions uncallable

Tags: typescript

```
type Container<T> = T extends any[] ? ArrayContainer<T> : ObjectContainer<T>

type ArrayContainer<T> = {
  set(arr: T, index: number): void
}

type ObjectContainer<T> = {
  set(obj: T): void
}

const testContainer = {} as any as Container<{ boxedNumber: number } | number>

// Does not compile
testContainer.set(33)
```

The conditional type decides to return an `ObjectContainer<{ boxedNumber: number }> | ObjectContainer<number>` making calling any function on ObjectContainer impossible.

Is there any way to force the return of an `ObjectContainer<{ boxedNumber: number } | number>`?

Using the latest 2.8 version available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @TitianCernicovaDragomir, your issue is that conditional types with a bare type parameter `T` in `T extends XXX ? YYY : ZZZ` ends up distributing over a union in `T`.  This is [as designed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21870), but there is a [de-facto standard workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21870#issuecomment-364763990) for it: "box" the `T` and `XXX` into a one-tuple as in `[T] extends [XXX] ? YYY : ZZZ`.  This makes the conditional not depend on a bare type parameter and it no longer breaks up the union.  (Anything where the `T` ends up in a covariant position should work... `{a: T} extends {a: XXX}` would also work).  This is likely to keep working and be supported since [@ahejlsberg](https://github.com/ahejlsberg) is the one recommending it and he is the [main architect of conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) in TypeScript.

So in your case you would do

```
type Container<T> = [T] extends [any[]] ? ArrayContainer<T> : ObjectContainer<T>
```

And it will interpret `Container<string | number>` as `ObjectContainer<string | number>`, as you want.

But note that now `Container<string | number[]>` is interpreted as `ObjectContainer<string | number[]>`, since `string | number[]` is not by itself an array.  Is that okay?  Should it be `ObjectContainer<string> | ArrayContainer<number[]>`?   Or `ObjectContainer<string> & ArrayContainer<number[]>`?  Or something else?  Not sure.

Hope that helps; good luck.

Comment: Didn't you forget the actual solution `type Container<T> = [T] extends [any[]] ? ArrayContainer<T> : ObjectContainer<T>` ?

Comment: I'm fine with only pure Arrays getting into ArrayContainers and any unions going to ObjectContainer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that conditional types will iterate over the types in a union and apply the condition to each item in the union and union the result, so the result of `Container<{ boxedNumber: number } | number>` will be equivalent to `ObjectContainer<number> | ObjectContainer<{ boxedNumber: number; }>` not `ObjectContainer<number | { boxedNumber: number; }>`.

You could create an intersection type of `Container<{ boxedNumber: number }>`  and Container which will behave similarly to what you expect from `Container<number | { boxedNumber: number }>`

```
const testContainer = {} as any as Container<{ boxedNumber: number }> & Container<number>
testContainer.set(33)
testContainer.set({ boxedNumber: 19})
```

Comment: If OP wants to prevent the conditional from distributing over the union, the de-facto standard way is to "box" the condition into a one-tuple like `type Container<T> = [T] extends [any[]] ? ArrayContainer<T> : ObjectContainer<T>`.

Comment: @jcalz I did not know that :) 10x. Will you add the answer, it is yours :) ?

Comment: @jcalz Oh wow, never would have thought of that. It works anyway! How likely is this to break in the future? Happy to approve this if you post an answer, yes.

Comment: Uh, okay sure, let me find documentation and I'll post an answer.

Comment: One issue there is with this indirection (I think) is that it's no longer possible to refine that boxed type param:

e.g  [T] extends [any[]] ? do something with T[number]

Comment: I usually work around that with something like `T[number & keyof T]`.  Or you can do the ugly `[T] extends [any[]] ? (T extends any[] ? T[number] : never) : ... `

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need additional type parameter.

```
type Container<T, R> = T extends any[] ? ArrayContainer<R> : ObjectContainer<R>;

type ArrayContainer<T> = {
  set(arr: T, index: number): void
}

type ObjectContainer<T> = {
  set(obj: T): void
}

const testContainer = {} as Container<{}, number>;
testContainer.set(10);
```